# React Router: navigate() from one screen to another does not pass state/parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Being pretty new to React, I'm facing an issue with navigating between 2 components.

My app is as follows:
App.js:

```
 <div className="App">

      <AuthProvider>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <CartProvider>
            <SiteHeader/>

            <div>
              <Routes>
                {getRoutes(routes)}
                <Route path="/auth" element={<AuthPage />} />
                <Route path="/cart" element={<CartPage />} />
                <Route path="/search_results" element={<SearchResultPage />} />
                <Route exact path="/_healthz" element={<HealthPage />} />
                <Route path="/orders" element={<OrderPage />} />
                <Route path="/category/:id" element={<CategoryPage />} />
                <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductPage />} />
                <Route path="/recipe/:id" element={<RecipePage />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>

          </CartProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </AuthProvider>

    </div>
```

As you can see, there is the SiteHeader component on every page.
On this SiteHeader Component, I have a search field, triggering a navigate() to SearchResultPage
Although the navigation itself is working (SearchResultPage is displaying), the parameters passed to navigate() are not propagated:

```
  const search = () => {
    console.log("Calling search =>" + searchTerm);
    navigate("/search_results",{ state: { searchText: searchTerm }});
  }
```

Below the code part for SearchResultPage:

```
export default function SearchResultPage(props) {
  console.log(props);
  let searchText = props.location.searchText
```

I don't understand why **props is empty** although I populated the navigate(path,state) correctly

Comment: Is your props empty or you are unable to get searchText state?

Comment: props is empty .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `react-router-dom` v6 Route components rendered via the element prop don't receive [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

You can use hook for getting the state given you are navigating to that page by passing some state value as follows:

```
const location = useLocation();
const searchText = location?.state?.searchText;
```

For getting `state` you need to access `props.location.state` and then subsequent state property if you are using `v5` or below.

Comment: thanks @GodWin, this worked and made my day. Any idea why the props did not propagate ?

Comment: Because `<Route/>` components rendered via `element` i.e. `<Route element={<Component/>}/>` don't receive any props of `route props` such as search, location, param, etc. In short, props are not passed in **V6**

Comment: @Sebastian There are not any route props in RRDv6, the `Route` component API changed significantly. Use the React hooks in the routed component.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```js
let searchText = props.location.searchText
```

to

```js
let searchText = props.location.state.searchText
```

Comment: thanks @user456, but props is empty